# Parse and convert datetime string

Tags: javascript, parsing, date

I have a SharePoint page that I am getting a string from and I want to display it on another. The format of the string is as follows: `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS TT`. I would like to change it to `mmm dd, yyyy`.

Comment: What is mmm ? Month ? Do you want to have Aug/May/Sep/... ?

Comment: Have a look at momentjs: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: I believe tt signifies AM or PM.

Comment: mmm would be month (Jan, Feb, Mar etc,)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing a date string is pretty simple. It seems you don't care about the time, so you just need to reformat the date part:

```
function formatDateString(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D+/g);
  var months = 'Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec'.split(' ');
  return months[--b[0]] + ' ' + b[1] + ', ' + b[2];
}

console.log(formatDateString('08/23/2014 23:32:01 AM')); // Aug 23, 2014
```

You can also parse the string to create a Date object, then format that:

```
function parseDateString(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D+/g);
  var h = b[3]%12 + (('' + b[6]).toLowerCase() == 'am'? 0 : 12);
  return new Date(b[2], --b[0], b[1], h, b[4], b[5]);
}

// Where the local timezone offset is UTC +10:00
console.log(parseDateString('08/23/2014 23:32:01 AM').toISOString()); // 2014-08-23T13:32:01.000Z
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. I will give it a shot tomorrow morning. I appreciate your help! Thanks to @Rocket Hazmat for the link. The timezone code will be very handy going forward.

Comment: &RobG, thanks for the code. Worked like a charm. Thanks to @Rocket Hazmat for the pointer to the timezone code as well. It will come in handy because we have projects that go across multiple timezones.